# What does <br[^>]*> regex mean?

Tags: java, regex

I have seen this regex in html document parsing.

I know that it matches `<br>` elements but i am not sure about `[^>]*>` part.
As far as i understand the regex says that an element should start with "br" but why do they need `[^>]*>` part. Why did not they use `<br*>` ?

Comment: Do you know what a character class is? `[...]`?

Comment: Consider `<br/>` and `<br></br>` which are both valid xhtml.

Comment: I think i got it. the `*` covers all elements between `<br>` and `</br>`

Comment: You can read more about **Character Classes** [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full breakdown of the regex `<br[^>]*>`:

1. Match the characters `<br` literally
2. Match any character that is NOT a `>`
3. Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
4. Match the character `>` literally

---

Also, you mentioned the regex `<br*>` in your post.

That would actually match `<b` and then it would match `r` 'between zero and unlimited times', followed by `>`.

Answer (score 8):

The [] signifies a set of characters.  If [] begins with ^ it means anything but these characters.  So  `[^>]*>` will match "as many characters of anything except for > followed by a >"   This is used to eat anything that's between br and >